# Matching anchor tag attribute regardless of order

Tags: regex, anchor, href

I am trying to write a regex match for anchor that should check data-username attribute in any order.

```
<a href="abac" class ="myclass" data-username = "username">Binod</a>
```

and

```
<a data-username="username" class ="myclass" href="abac">Binod</a>
```

Comment: Do you have any attempts so far?

Comment: i tried using two matches <a\ href=.*? data-username=.*?</a> and <a\ class=.*? data-username=.*?href=.*?</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex solved my problem. `<a\ .*?data-username=.*?>(?<linktext>.*?)</a>`

Answer (score 0):

In general, parsing HTML is a much better solution than trying to match it with a regex.  That said, give this a try

```
/<a.*data-username\s*=\s*\"(.*?)\"/g
```

That should match regardless of where data-username shows up in the tag list, and will leave the actual username in the capturing group.